Are density perturbations possible in a globally homogeneous and isotropic universe such as ours...?
I would like to ask some questions about an interesting paper that was written back in the late 90's (https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9701131)
There, the authors propose how the universe may evolve from the near future to extremely far time scales
Near the end of it (Section VI, D.), they discuss entropy and heat death: They indicate that the temperature of the universe would be continually changing, so a continually expanding universe would not really ever arrive to a thermodynamic equilibrium.
However, if we consider local pockets or regions, the expansion can make that a comoving volume becomes adiabatic so at that local level entropy would reach a maximum value. So according to this paper, while global heat death would not be attained, local or "cosmological" heat death could occur
Then they consider the case for the different main possible geometries of the universe:

If it's closed it would probably end up in a big crunch, so thermodynamic equilibrium wouldn't really happen

If it's flat density perturbations of larger and larger scales could enter the horizon allowing the production of entropy so thermnodynamic equilibrium would be avoided even at that local level

The last case is an open universe: Here thermodynamic equilibrium could happen as density fluctuations become "frozen" at a finite length scale (although they give some caveats i.e. that the Bekenstein bound does not directly constrain entropy production in this case, so actually is an open question).


Once summarized, my questions about this paper are the following ones:

I think this argument, if you read section V.B., is based on suggesting the local/observable density parameter being different from the density parameter on a larger scale. I would say this is not the standard assumption when thinking about questions like this, rather we assume global homogeneity. So how can the authors' argument that the universe wouldn't reach thermodynamic equilibrium globally (or even locally if it was flat) be compatible with the assumption that the universe is globally homogeneous and isotropic? It is strange because early in the paper, they seem to be aware that the consensus was that the universe is globally homogeneous and isotropic (see page 34)...

It’s not clear to me that the local density can be different from the large scale density infinitely far in the future. Is this possible?



I think their point, based on your summary and notes, is that in our local Hubble patch, $(aH)^{-1}$, that everything is the typical cosmology: homogenous, isotropic, and importantly, flat. However, the matter outside our local patch that is still yet to be observed, \textit{could} have the effect of never reaching thermal equilibrium. A weird effect is that at our particle horizon, "inflation is constantly happening." I think the authors are trying to put this perspective in line with a long term universe and the concept of heat death.
